# active model serializer not working with rails-api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am using rails-api gem in my project for json api, and for that purpose I used active model serializer gem for serializing my objects but some how the objects are not being serialized using active model serializer.

I have a MessageSerializer inside of my serializers folder

```
class MessageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :sender_type, :subj, :body, :status, :sender

  def sender
    object.user.try('username')
  end
end
```

And my messages controller is as follows

```
class Api::MessagesController < Api::BaseController

  def index
    @messages = current_user.incoming_messages
    render json: @messages, serializer: MessageSerializer
  end

end
```

But the problem is that the serialized object thrown to client contains all the fields in message model ie; it contains created_at, updated_at fields too.

Seems like its not using serializer.

What might have gone wrong?
I searched a lot about it but didn't found any post that helped me.

Thanks

Comment: change this to `class Api::MessagesController < Api::BaseController` to `class Api::MessagesController < ApplicationController` and change this also     render json: @messages and try once

Comment: No not good. Api::BaseController class inherits ApplicaionController class. So basically its the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your BaseController, did you add the include bellow ?

`include ActionController::Serialization`

Comment: this is the correct solution. never downgrade the gem.

Answer (score 10):

What version of AMS are you using?

I had this same issue and was able to fix it by changing the AMS version from 0.9.X to 0.8.X. This can be done by adding a version number to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.0'
```

There are notes about this on the AMS GitHub repo.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#maintenance-please-read

Comment: Thank you!  Would have wasted hours before realizing this!

Answer (score 5):

That's because the serialization is not loaded by default in rails-api.
You have to do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ::ActionController::Serialization
end
```

Comment: That does not change anything for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't downgrade, I spent some time trying different things and at the end I get to a pattern like this:

```
def sender
  if object.sender
    serializer = SenderSerializer.new(object.sender)
    ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi.new(serializer).as_json[:senders]
  end
end
```

it's ugly but it did the trick for me.

For a has_many relation, you can do something like this:

```
def attachments
  attachments = object.attachments.to_a
  return [] if attachments.empty?
  serializer = ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer.new(attachments, each_serializer:AttachmentSerializer)
  ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi.new(serializer).as_json[:attachments]
end
```